# How do you refer to the period from 2000 to 2009?

Tags: dates

It's so natural using "the 90's" and similar to refer to decades in the 20th century. But what about 2000 to 2009? It feels strange to use "the ones" or even "the tens" for 2010 to 2019.

Comment: We won't know for another ten years or so.

Comment: Uh ... La Belle Epoque Redux?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:
1) Use "2000-2009" with an en-dash
2) "The first decade of the twenty-first century"

I guess you could also say "From 2000 to 2009 ..." but it could appear awkward depending on the sentence.

Comment: I would guess redmint is asking whether we should call it "The Zero Years" or something.